# how can i get this result using regexp in php?

Tags: php, regex

how can i get this result using regexp in php?

please see my codes bellow:

a.php

```
/*
 *

-----------<jy:op>
{"name":"jimmy"}
-----------</jy:op>

-----------<jy:desc>
my name is jimmy
-----------</jy:desc>

 *
 */
```

test.php

```
<pre>
<?php

$code=file_get_contents('a.php');
preg_match_all('@<jy:(\w+)>.*</jy:(\1)>@is',$code,$result);
print_r($result);

// how can i get this result using regexp in php?
// the regex before is not correct.
array(
    'op'=>'{"name":"jimmy"}',
    'desc'=>'my name is jimmy'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that your `.*` matches as much as it can, until your second closing tag. To change this behavior, you can set the [ungreedy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier to your regex:

```
preg_match_all('@<jy:(\w+)>.*</jy:(\1)>@iUs',$code,$result);
```

If the content can't contain `<`, you can also use this regex:

```
preg_match_all('@<jy:(\w+)>[^<]*</jy:(\1)>@is',$code,$result);
```

without making the regex non-greedy.

Comment: Yes, more complete than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
(?s)<jy:op>\R*(.*?)\r?\n.*?<jy:desc>\R*(.*?)\r?\n
```

Use preg_match to retrieve the matches from Group 1 and Group 2

See demo here: http://regex101.com/r/xH8gF7